# How to use getWritableDatabase in SQLite database's onCreate() function? (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am writing an android app. I need to make an SQLite database and populate it when at its creation. So I am trying to populate it in it's onCreate() function. However, to insert data in the database, one needs to use db.getWritableDatabase(). But one can't do this inside the onCreate() function of the database, as that would mean calling the database during it's creation( it throws an error). So how to use getWritableDatabase() inside the onCreate() function of the database?

Comment: can you edit your question and include the code that you are currently using?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) out.

Comment: @FoamyGuy : onCreate's declaration looks like this: void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db). I am just using db.insert() to put in values, and it is not working..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, to insert data in the database, one needs to use db.getWritableDatabase().

No, you need a `SQLiteDatabase` instance. One is provided to the `onCreate()` method of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` -- use that.

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/Constants), I have an `onCreate()` that looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
      db.beginTransaction();
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE constants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, value REAL);");

      ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

      cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Death Star I");
      cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_DEATH_STAR_I);
      db.insert("constants", TITLE, cv);

      cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Earth");
      cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
      db.insert("constants", TITLE, cv);

      // several more inserts here

      cv.put(TITLE, "Gravity, Venus");
      cv.put(VALUE, SensorManager.GRAVITY_VENUS);
      db.insert("constants", TITLE, cv);

      db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally {
      db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I currently am using what you said, but the data is not being inserted into the database!

Comment: @user2213396: Then apparently you have a bug in your code, that you need to fix. I have posted a sample `onCreate()` and a link to a project that uses it.